# InDesign: override master page text style while maintaining master page text content?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, page-layout, master-page

Say I've got a master page with a text box on it, and in that text box I have the text "cat." I color the text black. I then apply this master to a basic document page, allow overrides on that page's local instance of that text box by Ctrl+Shift+clicking it, and then change the text color to blue. Now if I go back to my master page layout and change the text from "cat" to "dog," and then I go back to my local page (where I'd previously re-colored the text blue), the text is still "cat"; it hasn't been updated to "dog."

Is there a way to allow local overrides to text **style**, but maintain the live link back to the actual master page text box **content**? I could've sworn InDesign used to do this back in the day. Are there options / toggles for this sort of thing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No way to achieve that.

Once you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the text box, it becomes detached from the master information and literally moves to the page.

At that point, on that specific page, the master is no longer pushing a text box, and there is no "live" update. You can re-apply the master, in which case your overrides are cancelled and the page goes back to mirror the master page.